# Django data not being inserted into postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This codes gets the system performance reading using flask and plots it on a Django webpage using Chart which refreshes every second. I am trying to store the data into postgresql however it is not working. No data is being inserted into the table that was created in the database.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse, request
from .models import Usage


def monitor(request):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/stats"
    data = requests.get(url)
    print(data.text)
    data2 = data.text
    return render(request, "home.html", {'alldata': data2})


def cpu_monitor(request):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/cpu"
    cpu_data = requests.get(url)
    cpu_data2 = cpu_data.json()

    for key in cpu_data2:
        cpu = cpu_data2['CPU']
        time = cpu_data2['Time']
        print(cpu)
        print(time)
        val = key

    return render(request, "chart.html", {'data': val})


def cp(request):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/cpu"
    cpu_data = requests.get(url)
    cpu_data2 = cpu_data.json()

    for key in cpu_data2:
        cpu = cpu_data2['CPU']
        time = cpu_data2['Time']
        print(cpu)
        print(time)
        val = [cpu]

    return HttpResponse(val)


def mm(request):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/memory"
    memory_data = requests.get(url)
    memory_data2 = memory_data.json()

    for key in memory_data2:
        memory = memory_data2['Memory Percentage']
        time = memory_data2['Time']
        print(memory)
        print(time)
        mem = [memory]

    return HttpResponse(mem)


def dk(request):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/disk"
    disk_data = requests.get(url)
    disk_data2 = disk_data.json()

    for key in disk_data2:
        disk = disk_data2['Used Partition']
        time = disk_data2['Time']
        print(disk)
        print(time)
        dsk = [disk]

    return HttpResponse(dsk)


def dkf(request):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/diskfree"
    free_disk_data = requests.get(url)
    free_disk_data2 = free_disk_data.json()

    for key in free_disk_data2:
        free_disk = free_disk_data2['Free Partition']
        time = free_disk_data2['Time']
        print(free_disk)
        print(time)
        dskf = [free_disk]

    return HttpResponse(dskf)


def ib(request):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/inb"
    ib_data = requests.get(url)
    ib_data2 = ib_data.json()

    for key in ib_data2:
        ibn = ib_data2['Received Bytes']
        time = ib_data2['Time']
        print(ibn)
        print(time)
        ibd = [ibn]

    return HttpResponse(ibd)


def ob(request):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/oub"
    ob_data = requests.get(url)
    ob_data2 = ob_data.json()

    for key in ob_data2:
        obn = ob_data2['Received Bytes']
        time = ob_data2['Time']
        print(obn)
        print(time)
        obd = [obn]

    return HttpResponse(obd)


def insert():
    sysMon = Usage
    sysMon.cpu = cp(request)
    sysMon.memory = mm(request)
    sysMon.freeDisk = dk(request)
    sysMon.usedDisk = dkf(request)
    sysMon.inbound = ib(request)
    sysMon.outbound = ob(request)
    sysMon.save()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Usage(models.Model):

    cpu = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    memory = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    freeDisk = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    usedDisk = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    inbound = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    outbound = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have defined an insert method which can save to the database, but you never call this method (at least not in the code you've shown)

Comment: @jdoer1997 I tried with the return function as well, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get clarity about the data type of each function.  A view function returns data of type HttpResponse.
You should change your data functions so that each returns data of the required type, not return a HttpResponse.  For example the mm function should return memory data, which in your Model is a CharField (it is text with a limit of 200 chars).  Make sure it returns text and not a Python list, not json, and not a HttpResponse.

Then call one view function, which will collect (from all the data functions) and save it before returning its HttpResponse.   For example:

```
#Data function. Returns the disk free data itself, not a HttpResponse
def dkf():
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/diskfree"
    free_disk_data = requests.get(url).json()
    #other disk processing to be written by you. dskf is a variable with Character (text) data.  How to get it is left to you
    return dskf

#Data function. Returns the memory data itself, not a HttpResponse
def mm():
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/memory"
    memory_data = requests.get(url).json()
    #other memory processing to be written by you.  mem is a variable with Character (text) data.  How to get it is left to you
    return mem


#View function.  Call in the browser as /insert
def insert(request):
    sysMon = Usage
    sysMon.memory = mm()     #calls mm function which returns memory data
    sysMon.freeDisk = dkf()  #calls dkf function which returns disk free data
    #call the other ones here
    sysMon.save()

    return HttpResponse("Usage data saved")
```

Also note that for data collections and saving to a database, you don't necessarily have to use a view (which requires a browser and a human to load the page).   You can create a Python script which loads the Django modules, and do the data collections from a back end, for example called periodically from cron (on  Linux), or Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thank you but what should I use instead or CharField if I want to insert a list instead of text. Currently the data type that is being returned is a list.

Comment: That involves your database design, and is a whole new question.  But if you want to track a server's performance over time, you should add a DateTimeField to the Usage class (and to the database).  If you have this, you can take just the latest item from each list, so that the Usage entry has a cpu, mem, disk etc entry for that specific moment.   In this way, you don't need to insert a list, as a list of such values not matched to any  DateTime is probably not very useful for anything.

Comment: Alright, this gave me an idea on other alternatives. Thank you